# Will AWS ecs re-launch exited java processes in contianers?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I have a java app that I am running via Docker on AWS via the entrypoint:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar", "-Xmx600m", "/app.jar"]
```

I am running this on AWS ECS. If the java process dies for whatever reason, will the cotnainer be re-launched?

Answer (score 2):

If you run this as an [ECS Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs_services.html), then yes, when the container exits, the task will be stopped and a new task will be created with a new instance of the container.

If you run it as a Task, without a Service configuration, then no, ECS will not automatically replace the task.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if run as a service then it will be re-launched